How to integrate TestRail CLI with Testng NG via the Specification first aproach?
In documentation: https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/12609869124116-Specification-first-workflow
I can see how to update current test cases and add them into the new test run via JUnit, but I want to use TestNG and found the only Code-first approach example: https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7522744284820-Integrating-with-TestNG
Still not understand how to add test case id,s into my tests inside my code(via JUnit we can do this using @TestRail annotation, but it wasn't exist in Testng)

You can check out Railflow, a commercial tool for integrating TestNG with TestRail

Unfortunately, currently this is not supported.
There are 2 points:

there is no way to annotate tests in TestNG and get that out on the generated test report; you would need to implement a listener to achieve that.. something like what is provided on this GH project for another TM tool
the CLI isn't able to process TestNG XML test reports yet; it would need to process them, first of all, and also to process that information on the report if it exists; you can open a feature request on the corresponding GH project

